# ID number validation on workfusion

Tags: rpa, workfusion

I'm working on workfusion and my process is extracting 13 digit ID number from email subject line, how do I ensure the validity of the ID number i receive from the email?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use Java in WorkFusion, easiest is to use a regular expression. E.g. to validate 13 digit string:

```
if (idString.matches("[0-9]{13}")) {
     ....
}
```